# Spark Yarn Memory configuration

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark application that keeps failing on error:

> "Diagnostics: Container [pid=29328,containerID=container_e42_1512395822750_0026_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container."

I saw lots of different parameters that was suggested to change to increase the physical memory. Can I please have the some explanation for the following parameters?

- `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` (currently set to 0 so suppose to take the default which is 1GB so why we see it as 1.5 GB, changing it also dint effect the number)
- `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` (currently set to 0 so suppose to take the default which is 1GB so why we see it as 1.5 GB, changing it also dint effect the number)
- `mapreduce.map.java.opts/mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` set to 80% form the previous number
- `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=1GB` (when changing this then I see the effect on the max physical memory, but for the value 1 GB it still 1.5G)
- `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb/spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` can't find at all in configuration.

We are defining YARN (running with `yarn-cluster` deployment mode) using cloudera CDH 5.12.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
spark.driver.memory
spark.executor.memory
```

These control the base amount of memory spark will try to allocate for it's driver and for all the executors.  These are probably the ones you want to increase if you are running out of memory.

```
// options before Spark 2.3.0
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

// options after Spark 2.3.0
spark.driver.memoryOverhead
spark.executor.memoryOverhead
```

This value is an additional amount of memory to request when you are running Spark on yarn.  It is intended to account extra RAM needed for the yarn container that is hosting your Spark Executors.

```
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

When Spark goes to ask Yarn to reserve a block of RAM for an executor, it will ask a value of the base memory plus the overhead memory.  However, Yarn may not give it back one of exactly that size.  These parameters control the smallest container size and the largest container size that YARN will grant.  If you are only using the cluster for one job, I find it easiest to set these to very small and very large values and then using the spark memory settings mentions above to set the true container size.

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.map.java.opts/mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
```

I don't think these have any bearing on your Spark/Yarn job.

Comment: Yarn may not give it back - Why this can happen ?

Comment: For example, if your min allocation is set to 2GB, and you ask for 1.5GB, yarn will give you a 2GB container.

Comment: isnt this mapreduce.map.memory.mb the allocated memory for a container? if a spark dataframe cache size becomes larger than the container memory size, container will be killed. right?

Comment: mapreduce.map.memory.mb is specific to map reduce jobs.  The cache will automatically evict data if executor is approaching the max container size.  However if your actual work load requires more memory than the max container size then then yarn will kill the container.

Comment: where do I set `spark.driver.memory`, `spark.executor.memory` `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` ? is it in yarn-site.xml or some other config file?

Comment: it's in your $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf file.  Or alternatively you can specify them using --conf to spark-submit

Comment: @RyanWidmaier So if I set mapreduce.map.memory.mb too small then Spark will have problems in caching rdds?
Or does mapreduce.map.memory.mb and mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb have absolutely no effect on spark jobs?

Comment: The mapreduce.* settings have no effect on spark jobs.