# Unable to Launch Spark Shell in yarn mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Unable to Launch Spark Shell in yarn mode. When I run this `./spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client` It gets stuck here forever printing same messages.

```
18/03/14 20:11:38 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1521058297214
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-0-54:8088/proxy/application_1521058273627_0001/
     user: centos
18/03/14 20:11:39 INFO Client: Application report for application_1521058273627_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/03/14 20:11:40 INFO Client: Application report for application_1521058273627_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/03/14 20:11:41 INFO Client: Application report for application_1521058273627_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

Resource Manager UI says `ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM` and never moves from this state.

Here are my config files

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://NameNode:8020/</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
<value>131072</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.block.size</name>
<value>134217728</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- yarn-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>NameNode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.bind-host</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/yarn/local</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/yarn/log</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
<value>hdfs://NameNode:8020/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml** is empty since I use Spark but not map reduce

**Versions:** Spark 2.3 and Hadoop 2.7.3

**Unknowns**

After some Googling I see `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` but it is not listed in spark-env.sh however there is `SPARK_CLASSPATH` and not sure if I need to set this or if the above problem is related to this?

Not sure why I am unable to spawn spark shell in yarn mode and what it takes to fix? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Yarn UI and see if your spark job is asking for more memory or cores than Yarn has to give it.

You may be asking for more memory or cores for your Spark executors than Yarn has available to give it.  In which case you should set your spark executor sizing to something that fits.  To do that you would want to set these settings in your **$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf** file

spark.driver.memory
spark.executor.memory
spark.executor.cores

Also, when you submit the job with spark-submit you can use the flag **--num-executors** to specify how many executors you want.

This post describes the memory settings on both sides:
[Spark Yarn Memory configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701102/spark-yarn-memory-configuration/47701496#47701496)

Also, there are similar settings in yarn-site.xml for controlling how many cores can be used total and per container:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores
```

Comment: Do I need to set anything in mapred-site.xml if I need to run spark on yarn? The problem seems to be the moment I spawn spark shell in yarn mode like I point above one of the node managers gets killed and if I spawn another spark shell another node manager gets killed..And I am checking the resource manager logs and I dont see anything there. any idea?

Comment: No, I've always just left it at the default.  It's not used for spark

Comment: got it! in that case I am not sure why my node managers are getting killed when I spawn spark shell and hangs forever with these messages printing to console forever `18/03/14 20:11:39 INFO Client: Application report for application_1521058273627_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
`

Comment: if node managers get killed this way which log should I possibly see?